# OData Count in ASP.NET Core 6 doesn't return the count of data

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am able to get the count using an OData query of `$count=true`

```
https://localhost:7269/programs?$skip=20&$top=2&$count=true
```

but it didn't work and returned with the API this is my controller and the config of the OData.

```
[HttpGet("programs")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<ActionResult<EProgram>> GetPrograms()
{
     try
     {
         var programs = await _unitOfWork.EProgram.GetAllPrograms();

         return Ok(programs);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception GetAllPrograms start");
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         Console.WriteLine("Exception GetAllPrograms end");
         return BadRequest(ex.Message);
     }
}
 
services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(100))
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

I want to return the count of my data to can the pagination work correctly.  please I need help I'm trying many solution but the same issue appear

Comment: Try modifying the GetPrograms method in your controller to return IQueryable<EProgram> instead of ActionResult<EProgram>. Ensure _unitOfWork.EProgram.GetAllPrograms() returns IQueryable<EProgram> without executing the query (like calling .ToList()). Avoid executing the query in the controller; let OData handle it.

Comment: I would like to request you to mark the post as an answer it will help other in the future if they face similer issue

Answer (score 0):

Modify the GetPrograms method in your controller to return IQueryable instead of ActionResult. Ensure _unitOfWork.EProgram.GetAllPrograms() returns IQueryable without executing the query (like calling .ToList()). Avoid executing the query in the controller; let OData handle it.